# CORS Policy is not working as expected in Azure APIM

Tags: azure, cors, azure-api-management, azure-policy

Problem seems simple, but unable to fix it even after hours also.
Every time I create APIM instance and enabled CORS policy at inbound policies of global level , I am getting below error message while testing any API.

Error Message in Developer Portal:

```
Since the browser initiates the request, it requires Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) enabled on the server
```

I had enabled CORS policy by navigating to Portal Developer --> Portal Overview --> Enable CORS (clicked button) --> Manually Applied as well.

```
<cors allow-credentials="true">
    <allowed-origins>
        <origin>https://dev-apimdemo-apim.developer.azure-api.net</origin>
        <origin>https://dev-apimdemo-apim.azure-api.net</origin>
    </allowed-origins>
    <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="300">
        <method>*</method>
    </allowed-methods>
    <allowed-headers>
        <header>*</header>
    </allowed-headers>
    <expose-headers>
        <header>*</header>
    </expose-headers>
</cors>
```

I never added any custom policies or anything, just only enabled CORS.
**What am I missing still?**

Comment: Is your service in a vnet?

Comment: @MohamadHaidar NO

Comment: Humm, have a look at the developer consol (network and console tabs) and see if CORS is the actual error

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment like below:***

I created an Azure APIM and enabled **`CORS`** in the Portal overview:

[image]

Please check whether you have added **CORS policy at Global Level** like below:

*Go to APIs -> All APIs -> Inbound processing -> Add Policy -> CORS*

```json
<policies>
<inbound>
<cors  allow-credentials="true">
<allowed-origins>
<origin>https://testapim3394.developer.azure-api.net</origin>
</allowed-origins>
<allowed-methods  preflight-result-max-age="300">
<method>*</method>
</allowed-methods>
<allowed-headers>
<header>*</header>
</allowed-headers>
<expose-headers>
<header>*</header>
</expose-headers>
</cors>
</inbound>
<backend>
<forward-request/>
</backend>
<outbound/>
<on-error/>
</policies>
```

[image]

The CORS policy will be added in the Inbound processing like below:

[image]

I am able to **sign-in to the Developer Portal** like below:

[image]

***When I tried to execute the operation, I am able to successfully execute without any CORS error:***

Make sure that you are passing valid subscription key header.

[image]

***If still the issue persists,*** please try using the below CORS policy by including the methods:

```json
<cors>
<allowed-origins>
<origin>*</origin>
</allowed-origins>
<allowed-methods>
<method>GET</method>
<method>POST</method>
<method>PUT</method>
<method>DELETE</method>
<method>HEAD</method>
</allowed-methods>
<allowed-headers>
<header>*</header>
</allowed-headers>
<expose-headers>
<header>*</header>
</expose-headers>
</cors>
```

OR try replacing origin with **`<origin>https://*.azure-api.net/</origin>`**

**Reference:**

[Developer portal - Frequently asked questions - Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/developer-portal-faq#cors)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure out that it's because I wasn't passsing the header.

```xml
 <allowed-headers>
   <header>*</header>
</allowed-headers>
```

Full Azure API Management CORS Policy XML:

```xml
<policies>
<inbound>
    <cors allow-credentials="false">
        <allowed-origins>
            <origin>https://your-domain.com</origin>
            <origin>https://your-domain2.com</origin>
        </allowed-origins>
        <allowed-methods>
            <method>GET</method>
            <method>POST</method>
            <method>PUT</method>
            <method>DELETE</method>
            <method>HEAD</method>
        </allowed-methods>
           <allowed-headers>
            <header>*</header>
        </allowed-headers>
        <expose-headers>
            <header>*</header>
        </expose-headers>
    </cors>
</inbound>
<backend>
    <forward-request />
</backend>
<outbound />
<on-error />
</policies>
```

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as an answer. Instead, upvote Rukmini's answer.